# downlaod a file from folder on the basis of passing parameter from jsp to servlet in java

Tags: file, jsp, servlets

I have problem i am having a list of file on my jsp page now i want to download any one of the file by clicking on that file and all file will be in one folder which is available inside web content folder of eclipse but when I am clicking it is showing some error like that path is not found here I am providing error message of eclipse console

" SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [retrieve_file] in context with path [/ServletFileDownloadExample] threw exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Salary\teady1.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)"

here is my code .

```
 <body>
   <%
   String z;
    String FILE = "/Salary";
   try{
  File folder = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath(FILE));
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
   %>
   <table width="600" height="300"align=center cellspacing=0 border="0" cellpadding=0>
   <% 

      for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
      {
        if(listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
        {
             z = listOfFiles[i].getName();

             %>
             <tr><td><a href = "retrieve_file?f1=<%=z%>"><%=z%></a></td>
              </tr>

              <% 
            System.out.println("z is:" +z);

          System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          }
        else if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) 
        {
          System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }

      }
      }catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
          %>
         </table>
      </body>



    public class retrieve_file extends HttpServlet {
    private static final int BUFSIZE = 0;
    String FILE = "/Salary";
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 
    String f1 = request.getParameter("f1");
    File  file = new File(FILE, f1);
    System.out.println("file is :"+file);
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
     String relativePath = getServletContext().getRealPath(FILE);
      System.out.println("relativePath = " + relativePath);

    // obtains ServletContext
     ServletContext context = getServletContext();
   // gets MIME type of the file
   String mimeType = context.getMimeType(f1);
    if (mimeType == null) {        
    // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
    mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
   }
   System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);
  // modifies response
   response.setContentType(mimeType);
   response.setContentLength((int) file.length());

    // forces download
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
   String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", file.getName());
   response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    // obtains response's output stream
   OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

   byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  int bytesRead = -1;

  while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }
   inStream.close();
  outStream.close();     
}}
```

Comment: *I have one problem* what is problem? Is there any exception? where did you get stuck?

Comment: sir when i am clicking on links its not going to that servlet and not returning anything...

Comment: try ./retrieve_file instead of retrieve_file

Comment: no same response when i have not attached that servlet that moment it was showing that requested file not available but now after attaching its not giving any response ... i think some problem in servlet code..

Comment: I have edited my question so please review it and let me know if anyone can help me..

Answer (score 0):

(Too much content for a comment.)

1. Instance variables
2. Immediate overwrite of `file`
3. `doGet` does too much
4. Reinvention of stream copy utils
5. Inconsistent, non-canonical naming

**1.** In this case, they're harmless, but since they're harmless, they should be `static final`. In most cases, servlet instance variables are a Bad Idea unless you're quite certain you can deal with concurrent access. I'm guessing this is not the case.

**2.** You initialize `file` twice, in rapid succession. Makes no sense.

**3.** The `doGet` method is working at multiple levels of abstraction; this is almost always bad. Refactor.

**4.** During that refactoring you'll probably find some things have already been done before.

**5.** Names with all upper-case letters are `static final` vars in Java. Similarly, class names should be `CamelCased`. This makes things easier to read for people looking at your code.

If it's "not going to that servlet" then make sure you actually have it mapped in your `web.xml` which you do not include. If it's mapped correctly, and your link is correct, it's likely the servlet *is* getting hit.

There are multiple points of failure in your servlet code, and you provide essentially no usable information you can use to debug. Consider using some actual logging to determine *where* in the file download process your code and/or configuration are failing.

Comment: thanks i understood all the things but not getting solution and it is mapped correctly in web.xml and m still looking for solution..